# multiple release branch question

Tags: svn

I am new to svn. We are migrating to svn from harvest.
We are working on 3 different releases at a time. So we are thinking to make 3 branches by copying over from trunk and parallally work on them. No development will happen on trunk.
trunk will hold whatever is in production.

Say we have REL120,REL121,REL122 branches.
REL121 is created from REL120 and REL122 is created from REL121.
Whenever there is a commit to REL120, we merge that change in REL121 and REL122
whenever there is a commit in REL121, we merge that in REL122

and when we ship REL120 to production, we merge trunk with REL120

Is this a good way of branching? Or something can be improved in this. Please share your thoughts.

Vadiraj

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the approach.
Although, I would recommend you to make your merges less frequent and merge the code all the way up to the tree. For Eg;

**This is a logical structure of your repository**

```
|- trunk
|- branches
   |- Release 120
      |- Release 121
         |- Release 122
```

Now, Whenever you need to merge the chanegs of **Release 122**, they should be merged all the way up to trunk ... First to **Release 121**, then **Release 120** and then to **trunk** (Considering that **Release 120** is branched out from trunk)

Ideally, the merges should go up the tree (from child branches to parent) and not the opposite.

P.S. Is these three releases are not dependent on each other, then there is no need to create such a hierarchy. Just branch then individually from the trunk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changes that go in REL120 should be present in REL121 and REL122. But changes that go in REL121 should not be present in REL120 or changes that go in REL122 should not be present in REL121. REL120 will be released first, then REL121 and then REL122. It may happen so that changes in REL120, REL121,REL122 may all be in different modules all together or even the modules may clash. But REL121 should always contain changes made to the module in REL120 irrespective of whether REL121 changes are in that module or not. So, do you suggest us to make all branches from trunk?

Comment: Yes, In that case I would recommend that you branch out Rel 122 from the trunk first and then branch Rel 121 and 120 from it respectively. Because, if we see logically, You are putting Release 120 in PROD first and still it's child branches (created at the very beginning) are under development. This would cause instability. Apparently, if Release 121 was meant to be a Patch over Release 120, then it should have been branched out after 120 is LIVE. Or, on the contrary... you can create individual branches out from trunk and then do the merges between them as required

Comment: that means development will never happen on trunk right? When we ship 120 to production we should merge it with the trunk, so that trunk will always have whatever is there in production. Do the merges between branches as and when required. Am I right?

Comment: That's not the case. You can still develop the code in trunk. Choice is yours. The concept id that you create a branch for some release from trunk, and after the branch release is LIVE, you merge it back... still continuing the trunk development.

Answer (score 0):

For us, we will always do a branch or more branches from the main trunk. This way when we are done with the branch, then we will merge the branch back to the main trunk. This practice is specify in the svn documentation and you should read [it](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge) if you are new to svn.